# Get font information using pdfminer

Tags: python, fonts, pdfminer

How to get the font style and font color of a character using pdfminer?

I have got the matrix attribute of LTChar, but I am unable to figure out the columns in the matrix.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you convert pdf to HTML. You will get the font related information.

Comment: Converting pdf to HTML is not efficient in my case. Is there any other way to get the same?

Comment: Formatting of text is relevet in HTML. So am not aware about the other options. I done this with pdf to HTML using `pdf2html`.